# Is Safari's Reader mode cached?

Tags: html, safari

... and if so, is there way to refresh it?

**Background:**
I discovered that Safari's reader mode (version 7.1.3) was ignoring some content on my page; my hypothesis was that the algorithm (which [appears to use Readability](https://superuser.com/questions/387572/how-does-safaris-reader-work-and-when-does-it-show-up/#answer-387573)) didn't like some of my markup. To test this I started experimenting by editing the markup to see if this would have an affect. While refreshing the browser showed this edits in Safari's normal mode, when I hit the Reader button it still displays the previous version of the page. No amount of edits seems to change this; each time the Reader mode shows the first version.

**What I tried:**
I tried clearing caches, and made multiple edits, some very minor and some with lots of changes, with no success.

**What I expected:**
Simply that when a page content changes, reader mode would update accordingly.

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate on Programmers. This isn't really about a specific issue.

Comment: @Carcigenicate If you re-interpret the question as 'Safari's reader mode doesn't update when page content is edited/reflect current page content' you wouldn't consider that sufficiently specific?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it thoroughly enough.

Comment: A couple of interesting links: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader and http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/03/18/safari-reader.js